# How can I export the trained SVM model from MatLab to use in Android(Java)

Tags: java, android, matlab, machine-learning, libsvm

I trained an SVM model on Matlab and saved as .mat file. How can I save it in a format that I can use with Java? or is there any other ways to use my MatLab model on Java(Like using the models parameters to create a new predictor on Java)?
Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

[try this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100293-how-can-i-read-mat-files-from-java?) or you can make it your self by loading the file and reading the file structure fields [here](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/ch10_in8.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply:) I can read the structure fields but how can i make a new predictor with those values on Android?

Comment: this is an other matter :p

Comment: you should implement the predictor system, the training results in your case are like the engine (you must have a car to put the engine inside)